# Returning Form values to post action in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which has no Model. On design time it has 2 drop down lists with values. Below is my view code:

```
    if (string.Equals("Home", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()))
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Home",FormMethod.Post,new {@class="firstform"}))
    {


            <div class="field vert">
                <select>                        
                    <option>Home</option>
                    <option>Health</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="field vert">
                <select>                       
                    <option>Education</option>
                    <option>Designation</option>
                </select>
            </div>



              <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Get Now"/>

}

    }
```

My action is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(FormCollection f)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

In action I couldn't find form values, Can you please guide me what I should do or what I m missing to get values in `Submit` action.

I m putting break point and checking form collection has nothing. Please help

Comment: You need to give your controls a `name` attribute e.g. `<select name="abc">...`. But why not just use a view model and take advantage of MVC's model binding features?

Comment: @StephenMuecke these are just drop down lists which are static. Dont expect them changing. do you still recomment using model binding ?

Comment: Personally I would use a view model for the benefits of using strongly typed html helpers, model binding and future flexibility, but this is a simple case so I leave it up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default binding in MVC is with **name** **attribute** so just give your select tag name attribute as shown :

```
 <div class="field vert">
     <select name="a">                        
         <option>Home</option>
         <option>Health</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 <div class="field vert">
      <select name="b">                       
         <option>Education</option>
         <option>Designation</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

and get selected dropdown value with the help of name attribute at post controller.

Comment: @user576510..i don't think its a hard and fast rule that you should use strongly typed dropdownlist if you have a static simple dropdown then you are on a right way just give select a name and get its value on post controller.